# Bootstrap mobile nav, want to "drop over" existing content (z-index)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, position, z-index

I have a mobile nav using bootstrap and I want to collapse over existing content when it drops down (as opposed to it pushing content down).

I have tried setting `position: relative` and `z-index: 9999` on everything I can think of:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.navbar-collapse {
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    position: relative !important;
    z-index: 9999 !important;

}
.navbar {
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    position: relative !important;
    z-index: 9999 !important;

}
.collapse {
    position: relative !important;
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}
}
```

So far nothing has worked, anybody know of a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So like this http://jsfiddle.net/7ocbs21d/1/

```
.navbar-static-top {
    position:absolute;
   width:100%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using properties like relative for your navbar.  If you use bootstraps fixed navbar then you'll be able to achieve your desired outcome.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

Here's a fiddle with an example http://jsfiddle.net/7ocbs21d/

Comment: I would like to do it like this but unfortunately the nav cannot be fixed to the top of the screen, it needs to keep scroll up and remain at top of page.